# Sending Quote directly from Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

i am trying to find a way to send generated Quote directly from CRM to my client + at the same time adding add completed task of doing that. 
As i understood only way to do this is by downloading quote as a template and using a mail merge. And then creating a task by hand. I want you to prove me wrong, about this one..

Comment: You may want to rephrase this post into a question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mscrm-addons have a product called [Document Core Pack](http://mscrm-addons.com/Products/AddonsforMSCRM2011/DocumentsCorePack/tabid/170/Default.aspx).  That will generate much nicer quote document, attach to an email (as pdf if desired), save the document to CRM and / or SharePoint, create a history item etc etc for you.  I've used it in a couple of implementations and am impressed by its ease of use.  Have a look at that.